# finding the longest name in a class

Tags: c++

i have 3 classes human,teacher and student, teacher and student inherits the properties of human my classes are like this below

```
class human{
        public:
        string firstname;
        string lastname;

}

class teacher:public human{
        public:
        int card_number;
}

class student:public human{
        public:
        int studen_num;
}
```

i want to write a function that compares the lastnames of the `teachers` and that of `students`,then it should print the one with the longest name with the help of an array,how can i do this ?

this is what i tried

```
void st(students1,teachers2){
if (str_length(s1.name) > str_length(s2.name))
   cout<<s1.name;
   else
   cout<<s2.name;

}
```

i do not know how i can do it with arrays

Comment: Why does it need to be an array?

Comment: Is this your homework and have you tried anything

Comment: let me show you what i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use const when you're passing in a pointer that will not be altered. You shouldn't be passing as a pointer unless you plan to have the argument as NULL at some point. In this case we always want the vector to have at least one human. It's a good idea to use std::vector for a container rather than an array if it's going to be dynamic. This way you don't need to keep track of how many humans you have.

```
string max( const std::vector< Human > & _human_vec )
{
   std::vector< Human >::iterator human_vec_it = _human_vec.begin();
   std::string longest_last_name;
   for( human_vec_it; human_vec_it != _human_vec.end(); ++human_vec_it )
   {
      if( *human_vec_it.lastname.size() > longest_last_name )
         longest_last_name = *human_vec_it.lastname;
   }

   return longest_last_name;
}
```

This is my first answer on stackoverflow so I hope I'm following the rules correctly. Please advise me if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are ambiguities in your question:

- Do you have two arrays, one for `teachers` and one for `students`?
- Are there a one-to-one correspondence between a teacher and a student? Otherwise comparing teachers against students to find the longest name isn't meaningful if you just want any `human` with the longest lastname.

Assuming that you just want the `human` with longest `lastname`:

- Store all the `teachers` and `students` in a `human` array (Polymorphism)
- Iterate through this array once and check the length the `lastname` of each element
- If this length greater than the `max` seen so far, update the corresponding `max` value.

Comment: i want something like this thanks let me check

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sorting the arrays descending order by name length.
The name at the first position will be the longest:

```
bool Order_By_Name_Length(const Human& h1, const Human& h2)
{
    const unsigned int h1_length = h1.firstname.length() + h1.lastname.length();
    const unsigned int h2_length = h2.firstname.length() + h2.lastname.length();
    return h1_length > h2_length;
}

//...
std::sort(&students1[0], &students[LAST_STUDENT_INDEX], Order_By_Name);
std::sort(&teachers1[0], &teachers[LAST_TEACHER_INDEX], Order_By_Name);
```

This may be easier by adding a `length` method to human:

```
class Human
{
  public:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
  unsigned int length(void) const
  {
      return firstname.length() + secondname.length();
  }
};

bool Order_By_Name2(const Human& h1, const Human& h2)
{
    return h1.length() > h2.length();
}
```